# Передача массива между фрагментами

Tags: android, массивы, android-fragment

Можете написать пример передачи массива с одного фрагмента в другой 
Знаю что так мы отправляем

```
 Fragment f = new Fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("massive", massive);
        f.setArguments(bundle);
```

А так принимаю

```
int massive= getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("massive");
```

Но правильно ли я это реализую?

Answer (score 3):

Нужно вот так отправить:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putIntArray("array", array);
FragmentClass fragment = new FragmentClass();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Вот так получить:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int array[] = getArguments().getIntArray("array")    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

Comment: сделал как вы написали,при выводе выводит null

Comment: Значит вы что не так делаете, укажите в вопросе в какой момент вы создаете второй фрагмент и в каком месте.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756433/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9